# continuous f(x) and continuous f '(x) relation

Tags: real-analysis

IF $g(x)$ is prove to be not continuous at one point p. 
$g'(x)$ is also not continuous?

**

> question is asking to show that g'(x) is not continuous at 0.

**

let say we have

$$g(x) =\begin{cases} 
x^2 sin(1/x) & x != 0 \\  
0, x = 0 \end{cases}$$

i'm going to show that  g(x) is not continuous

if  $|x-0| < \delta \\$
, and define the  x < $\delta$  and   $\delta  <= \epsilon/2$.

h = x + $\epsilon$

|g(h) - g(0) | = $|x^2sin(1/x) - 0|  $

then   if we put x as $\epsilon/2 $

$$\epsilon<(\epsilon/2)^2 sin( 2/\epsilon) $$ 
then
$$ |x^2sin(1/x) - 0|   > \epsilon$$

Therefore, This function is not continuous at point 0.

can we conclude this to $g'(x) $ is not also continuous?

Comment: Your function $g(x)$ is continuous everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your function $g(x)$ is continuous everywhere. So you will not be able to show it is not continuous.

We now look at a related question that you do not explicitly raise.

If a function is differentiable at $p$, then it is automatically continuous at $p$. For if 
$$\lim_{x\to p}\frac{g(x)-g(p)}{x-p}=f'(p),$$ then 
$$\lim_{x\to p} (x-p)\frac{g(x)-g(p)}{x-p}=\lim_{x\to p}(x-p)f'(p)=0$$
and therefore $\lim_{x\to p}g(x)-g(p)=0$, meaning that $\lim_{x\to p}g(x)=g(p)$. This says $g(x)$ is continuous at $p$.

Equivalently, if $g(x)$ is not continuous at $p$, then $g(x)$ is not differentiable at $p$.  However, you will not be able to use this kind of argument to show that $g'(x)$ is not coninuous at $0$, since in fact $g(x)$ is continuous at $0$.

**Added:** The question has changed. Directly from the definition of the derivative, you can prove that $g'(0)=0$. For we are looking at the limit of $\frac{x^2\sin(1/x)-0}{x-0}$, that is, of $x\sin(1/x)$. The $\sin(1/x)$ part stays bounded, and the $x$ part approaches $0$, so the product approaches $0$.

To show $g'(x)$ is not continuous at $0$, calculate $g'(x)$ for $x\ne 0$ using the ordinary rules of differentiation. We get $-\cos(1/x)+2x\sin(1/x)$. It is not hard to show that the limit of this as $x\to 0$ does not exist. The $2x\sin(1/x)$ part behaves very nicely, but $-\cos(1/x)$ oscillates wildly as $x\to 0$.

Comment: > question is asking to show that g'(x) is not continuous at 0. How do we do that?

Comment: I added a sketch of a solution of that part. The first answer dealt with what you had written.

Comment: for the continuous of g(x) proof, which I had wrote. which part is wrong? I found its not continuous at 0. strange

Comment: The $\epsilon$ stuff is used in an incomprehensible manner. To make $|x^2\sin(1/x)|\lt \epsilon$, it is enough to make $|x|\lt \sqrt{\epsilon}$, since $|\sin(1/x)|\le 1$.